# Angular subscribe function with HTTP Get never returning

Tags: angular, typescript, http

This Component calls the service.

```
  req: Observable<Object> = this.blogEntryService.testFunction();

  constructor(private blogEntryService: BlogEntryService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("Init page");
    this.req.subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res)
    });
  }
```

Then the service returns the observable:

```
  testFunction() {
    console.log("Testing connection")
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  }
```

When executing there are only 2 logs:

- Testing connection
- Init page

There is no result logged

I have inspected the app with AngularDevTools and checked the observable is created, it is.

Any idea of what could be the issue? No error is ever logged.

Note: This exact code works with InMemoryDatabase while testing.

Comment: Try this.blogEntryService.testFunction().subscribe

Comment: It calls testFunction() but does nothing else. Network tab is still empty too.

Comment: Http requests in Angular are cold subscriptions, you must subscribe on the observable object returned by the testFunction in order for it to fire, so what Taras suggested should work

Comment: Isn't `this.req.subscribe()` enough?

Answer (score 0):

Tested this code, works as expected

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { BlogEntryService } from './blog-entry.service';

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private blogEntryService: BlogEntryService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.blogEntryService.testFunction().subscribe({ next: response => {console.log(response);}});
  }
}
```

**blog-entry.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BlogEntryService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  testFunction(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  }
}
```

In your **app.module.ts** add HttpClientModule to imports array as this

imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule]

Outputs user { userId: 1, id: 1, title: "delectus aut autem", completed: false }

Comment: I have the same and the correct imports and the result still doesn't show. The Observable is created but calling it with subscribe() does nothing

`[BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, AppRoutingModule, RouterModule.forRoot([]), AngularEditorModule, FormsModule, HttpClientTestingModule]`

Comment: Reproduce your code on codesandbox and i will help you

Comment: I just found the issue. `HttpClientTestingModule` blocks all http requests for a reason I don't know. Removing it is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing'` blocks all http requests. My solution was removing it for the time being